# How to set default mailto and cc addresses

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, default-settings

Every time I create a mail, I have to either enter or paste the email addresses into `To` and `CC` sections, the problem is most of the time the addresses are the same.

So I wonder can I do some setting that whenever I create a new mail, the addresses will be automatically entered ?

P/s : I'm using Outlook for desktop 2016

Answer (score 1):

Creating an email template(.oft) with the Recipients you would like, and then the next time you would like to email them, you just need to open this template and edit the email content.

[image]

Comment: Have you got your issue fixed? If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks.